# How many times can one accept or unaccept an answer?

Tags: discussion

What is the etiquette regarding accepting or unaccepting answer more than once? Actually, it deals with my question on large numbers. First I accepted an answer, then unaccepted it and accepted another answer but due to significant edits from my end one of the answerer also edited the answer. Now I am conflicted as to if I should unaccept answer **second time** and wait.

Comment: As many times as you need, I think... Keep in mind it's not necessary to accept an answer at all, but there's no issue with changing your selected answer to one that might be more helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

You should accept the **best** answer by your criteria.

The fact what answer is the **best** can change, when:

1. A new answer is added, better than the ones that existed before
2. An existing answer is edited, and therefore greately improved (I would be cautious when accepting answer that was initially poor and then significantly changed)
3. The accepted answer was edited, making it worse than it was (not very probable, I've never met such case)

When one of the above happens, in my opinion you're free to change the accepted answer.